# Search for a word in headers of another table, if word found pull header and all information in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Housekeeping info: I am working in Excel 2016, I have hundreds of sheets and additions and subtractions will need to be made over the years after the initial document is created so I am looking to automate as much of the sheets as I can.

Text is contained in cell B2. I'm looking for a formula that can look for that word across the headers of Table174, if found to be contained in any of the headers of Table174 (table174 is the identifier of the lookup table in the sheet I am working on), it will pull all the information in that headers column including the header.

So lets say the look up table is formatted as:

```
   Header Row      Boiler PM     Pump PM      Fan PM      Tank PM
                   Action 1a     Action 1b    Action 1c   Action 1d
                   Action 2a     Action 2b    Action 2c   Action 2d
                   Action 3a     Action 3b    Action 3c   Action 3d
                   Action 4a     Action 4b    Action 4c   Action 4d
```

The actions are a checklist and will all be different.

So if in the other sheet in cell B2 it says Boiler, the formula would output:

```
Boiler PM
Action 1a
Action 1b
Action 1c
Action 1d
```

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do accomplish this goal? Ultimately I am looking to pull the name of a checklist and the checklist itself with a formula from a base sheet so I only have to input the checklist once rather then searching for the proper checklist and copy and pasting hundreds of times.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination. As you are on ***Excel-2016*** you need to drag down the formula manually. Try-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$5,ROW($A1),MATCH($I$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harun24hr for your help! I was able to adjust this to my use. In newer version of excel would this formula auto populate as far down as there is information? For anyone coming along in the future and using a lookup table in another sheet like myself this was my final formula:
```=IFERROR(INDEX(Table174,ROW('XX-XX'!$A1),MATCH($B$2,Table174[#Headers],0)),"")```   Where Table174 is the lookup table, $B$2 is the location in that the word is found (this could also be substited with a word in the formula i.e "Fan PM", and 'XX-XX'!$A1 is the sheet and the starting row of the lookup table.

Comment: @BCOR Yes, In ***Microsoft-365*** formula will auto populate till last data. As soon as you enter new data formula adjust automatically.